# Trouble understanding 相変わらずとぼけた奴

Tags: meaning

I'm having trouble understanding this person is saying.  I understand he is complaining that someone is late but not much more after that.

> おそいぞ 10時ギリギリか 相変わらずとぼけた奴だぜ

Comment: To help us give a better answer,  can you elaborate on what part is specifically giving you trouble?

Comment: pretty much from 相変わらず onwards, i pretty much understand everything up until after ギリギリか

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to understand any Japanese sentence you're having trouble with is to try to parse it into its constituent parts first.

> おそい  late
>   ぞ  (emphasis/exclamatory particle)
>   10時ギリギリ  just barely 10 o clock
>   か  (rhetorical device)
>   相変わらず  as usual
>   とぼけた  (past tense of とぼける) absent-minded
>   奴  person (informal)
>   だ  is/are  (copula)
>   ぜ (emphasis/exclamatory particle)

Once you see the parts laid out like that, it's easier to attempt a translation. Here's a kind of loose translation of it (since I prefer 意訳 to 直訳).

> Hurry up! You've just barely made it by 10 o clock, huh? As usual you're such a scatterbrain!

Answer (score 0):

ぎりぎり means just in time, just at the edge. They just barely made it by 10 o'clock. 相変わらず means that the person does this often (arriving late). とぼける means to be stupid/silly. Btw you can look up all these words in a dictionary.

Comment: thank you very much, i really appreciate it.

Comment: `ぼける means to be mentally slow, stupid.` <-- ううん・・・ 「 **と**ぼける」です

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed that と.Thanks.